# Combinations of weighted elements in a set where weighted sum equal to fixed integer (in python)

Tags: python, combinations, knapsack-problem

I would like to find all the possible combinations of weighted elements in a set where the sum of their weights is **exactly** equal to a given weight W

Say I want to select k elements from the set `{ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' }` where `weights = {'A':2, 'B':1, 'C':3, 'D':2, 'E':1}` and `W = 4`.

Then this would yield :
`('A','B','E')
('A','D')
('B','C')
('B','D','E')
('C','E')`

I realize the brute force way would be to find all permutations of the given set (with `itertools.permutations`) and splice out the first k elements with a weighted sum of W. But I'm dealing with at least 20 elements per set, which would be computationally expensive.

I think using a variant of knapsack would help, where only weight (not value) is considered and where the sum of weights must be **equal** to W (not inferior).

I want to implement this in python but any cs-theory hints would help. Bonus points for elegance!

Comment: `itertools.permutation` gives back an iterator, not a list of all permutations. So you can step through the results and stop at the kth match.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - still wouldn't help with computational complexity unless the iterator returns results sorted on some certain value (in this case, sum of weights), which I guess it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping through all *n*! permutations is much too expensive. Instead, generate all 2^*n* subsets.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def weight(A):
    return sum(weights[x] for x in A)

# Copied from example at http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in xrange(len(s) + 1))

[x for x in powerset({'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'}) if weight(x) == W]
```

yields

```
[('A', 'D'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'E'), ('B', 'E', 'D')]
```

This can be converted to sorted tuples by changing the return part of the list comprehension to `tuple(sorted(x))`, or by replacing the `list` call in `powerset` with one to `sorted`.

Comment: Your comment is nice @fylow, but don't forget to check the checkmark to the left of this answer, to quantify your gratitude with some cold, hard rep points!

Comment: Got it @PaulMcGuire, I am not very well acquainted with stack overflow.

Comment: If the sets are going to be at least of size 20, then the above is going to take quite some time. For a set of N weights the complexity is O(2^N). For sets of about size 30 this will never end... I've posted a simple solution that works with larger sets of weights using a space/time tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an upper bound on the number of items in such sets? If you do and it is at most about 40, then the ["meet-in-the-middle" algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) as described in the [Wikipedia page on Knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0-1_knapsack_problem) can be quite simple and has significantly lower complexity than a brute-force computation.

Note: Using a more memory-efficient data structure than a Python dict, this could also work on larger sets. An efficient implementation should easily handle sets of size 60.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain, combinations, product

# taken from the docs of the itertools module
def powerset(iterable):
     "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
     s = list(iterable)
     return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in xrange(len(s) + 1))

def gen_sums(weights):
    """Given a set of weights, generate a sum --> subsets mapping.

    For each posible sum, this will create a list of subsets of weights
    with that sum.

    >>> gen_sums({'A':1, 'B':1})
    {0: [()], 1: [('A',), ('B',)], 2: [('A', 'B')]}
    """
    sums = defaultdict(list)
    for weight_items in powerset(weights.items()):
        if not weight_items:
            sums[0].append(())
        else:
            keys, weights = zip(*weight_items)
            sums[sum(weights)].append(keys)
    return dict(sums)

def meet_in_the_middle(weights, target_sum):
    """Find subsets of the given weights with the desired sum.

    This uses a simplified meet-in-the-middle algorithm.

    >>> weights = {'A':2, 'B':1, 'C':3, 'D':2, 'E':1}
    >>> list(meet_in_the_middle(weights, 4))
    [('B', 'E', 'D'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'E'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'E')]
    """
    # split weights into two groups
    weights_list = weights.items()
    weights_set1 = dict(weights_list[:len(weights)//2])
    weights_set2 = dict(weights_list[len(weights_set1):])

    # generate sum --> subsets mapping for each group of weights,
    # and sort the groups in descending order
    set1_sums = sorted(gen_sums(set1).items())
    set2_sums = sorted(gen_sums(set2).items(), reverse=True)

    # run over the first sorted list, meanwhile going through the
    # second list and looking for exact matches
    set2_sums = iter(set2_sums)
    try:
        set2_sum, subsets2 = set2_sums.next()
        for set1_sum, subsets1 in set1_sums:
            set2_target_sum = target_sum - set1_sum
            while set2_sum > set2_target_sum:
                set2_sum, subsets2 = set2_sums.next()
            if set2_sum == set2_target_sum:
                for subset1, subset2 in product(subsets1, subsets2):
                    yield subset1 + subset2
    except StopIteration: # done iterating over set2_sums
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick to doing this (somewhat) efficiently is to create sets of elements that have the same weight using the first k items.

Start with an empty set at k=0, then create your combinations for k using combinations from k-1.  Unless you can have negative weights, you can prune combinations with a total weight greater than W.

Here is how it plays out using your example:

comb[k,w] is the set of elements having a total weight w using the first k elements.
Braces are used for sets.
S+e is the set of sets created by adding element e to each member of S.

```
comb[0,0]={}
comb[1,0]={comb[0,0]}
comb[1,2]={comb[0,0]+'A'}
comb[2,0]={comb[1,0]}
comb[2,1]={comb[1,0]+'B'}
comb[2,2]={comb[1,2]}
comb[2,3]={comb[1,2]'B'}
comb[3,0]={comb[2,0]}
comb[3,1]={comb[2,1]}
comb[3,2]={comb[2,2]}
comb[3,3]={comb[2,3],comb[2,0]+'C'}
comb[3,4]={comb[2,3]+'C'}
comb[4,0]={comb[3,0]}
comb[4,1]={comb[3,1]}
comb[4,2]={comb[3,2],comb[3,0]+'D'}
comb[4,3]={comb[3,3],comb[3,1]+'D'}
comb[4,4]={comb[3,4],comb[3,2]+'D'}
comb[5,0]={comb[4,0]}
comb[5,1]={comb[4,1],comb[4,0]+'E'}
comb[5,2]={comb[4,2],comb[4,1]+'E'}
comb[5,3]={comb[4,3],comb[4,2]+'E'}
comb[5,4]={comb[4,4],comb[4,3]+'E'}
```

The answer is then comb[5,4], which simplifies to:

```
{
  {{'B'}+'C'},
  {{'A'}+'D'},
  {
    {{'A'}+'B'},
    {'C'},
    {'B'}+'D'             
  }+'E'
}
```

Giving all the combinations.

Comment: I made a mistake in my example which caused it to miss ('B','C') -- now fixed.